# html table tr onkeydown not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I am trying to make a keyboard navigated html table using tr keydown event, issue is keydown event is not getting fired when I press any key on table.

I tried using

```
onkeydown="method();"
```

and jquery

```
$("tr").keydown(function(event){});
```

but still keydown event is not getting fired.

link(nitinkabra.com/new_table)

below is an example of what i have done yet :

```
            <head>

            <script>
                    function keydwn() {
                        alert("herte");
                    }

            </script>

            <style>
            .selected:focus{background-color:green}
            .selected:hover{background-color:#fdfd02}
            </style>

            </head>
            <body>

            <div style="width:750px;max-width: 3200px;max-height:450px;overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x:scroll;">
                <div style="width:750px;max-width: 3200px;">
<table class='default_table' style="table-layout: fixed; width: .3200px; overflow: visible;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 300px">
                Ledger Name
            </th>
            <th style="width: 150px">
                Group
            </th>
            <th style="width: 300px">
                Address 1
            </th>
            <th style="width: 300px">
                Address 2
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px">
                Contact Person
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px">
                City
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px">
                State
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px">
                PIN
            </th>
            <th style="width: 150px">
                Phone
            </th>
            <th style="width: 150px">
                Mobile
            </th>
            <th style="width: 200px">
                E-Mail
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px">
                TIN
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px">
                Area
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px">
                Remarks
            </th>
            <th style="width: 100px">
                Opening
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px">
                Lock Credit Bill
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px">
                Limit on Amount
            </th>
            <th style="width: 100px">
                Limit on Bill
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px">
                Limit Credit Days
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

            <div style="width: 3405px;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden; max-height:430px;">

                <table id = "main_table" class='default_table' style="table-layout: fixed; width:100%;margin-top:-30px;">

                    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 300px">
            Ledger Name
        </th>
        <th style="width: 150px">
            Group
        </th>
        <th style="width: 300px">
            Address 1
        </th>
        <th style="width: 300px">
            Address 2
        </th>
        <th style="width: 120px">
            Contact Person
        </th>
        <th style="width: 120px">
            City
        </th>
        <th style="width: 120px">
            State
        </th>
        <th style="width: 120px">
            PIN
        </th>
        <th style="width: 150px">
            Phone
        </th>
        <th style="width: 150px">
            Mobile
        </th>
        <th style="width: 200px">
            E-Mail
        </th>
        <th style="width: 120px">
            TIN
        </th>
        <th style="width: 120px">
            Area
        </th>
        <th style="width: 120px">
            Remarks
        </th>
        <th style="width: 100px">
            Opening
        </th>
        <th style="width: 120px">
            Lock Credit Bill
        </th>
        <th style="width: 120px">
            Limit on Amount
        </th>
        <th style="width: 100px">
            Limit on Bill
        </th>
        <th style="width: 120px">
            Limit Credit Days
        </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

                    <tbody>
                            <tr id="0" class="selected" onkeydown="keydwn();">
                                <td style="width: 300px">
                                    ABC India Pvt. Ltd.
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">
                                    ABC Add 1, Chennai
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">
                                    Chennai
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">
                                    Chennai
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 200px">
                                    abc@yahoo.com
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">
                                    5000.00
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="1" class="selected" onkeydown="keydwn(event);">
                                <td style="width: 300px">
                                    Abhilash Loan Ac
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">
                                    Unsecured Loans
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">
                                    215, M.G.ROAD, BANGA
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 200px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">
                                    0.00
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="2" class="selected" onkeydown="keydwn(event);">
                                <td style="width: 300px">
                                    Abxd India Pvt Ltd
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">
                                    Sundry Debtors
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 200px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">
                                    0.00
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="3" class="selected" onkeydown="keydwn(event);">
                                <td style="width: 300px">
                                    Accum. Dep. on Building
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">
                                    Fixed Assets
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 200px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">
                                    0.00
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="4" class="selected" onkeydown="keydwn(event);">
                                <td style="width: 300px">
                                    Accum. Dep. on Computer &amp; Per.
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">
                                    Fixed Assets
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 200px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">
                                    0.00
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="5" class="selected" onkeydown="keydwn(event);">
                                <td style="width: 300px">
                                    Accum. Dep. on Furn. &amp; Fixt.
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">
                                    Fixed Assets
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 200px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">
                                    0.00
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="6" class="selected" onkeydown="keydwn(event);">
                                <td style="width: 300px">
                                    Accum. Dep. on Motor Car
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">
                                    Fixed Assets
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 200px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">
                                    0.00
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="7" class="selected" onkeydown="keydwn(event);">
                                <td style="width: 300px">
                                    Accum. Dep. on P &amp; M - I
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">
                                    Fixed Assets
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 300px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 150px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 200px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">
                                    0.00
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">

                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 120px">

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            <script>
            document.getElementById('0').focus();
            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Please short your code example!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You cannot have a `keydown` event on a `TR`, because, it is not focussable. Only focussed elements have `key*` events. So, change your code this way:

```
<tr tabindex="0">
```

So that it gets a focus. Now, when you move your focus, by using <kbd>Tab</kbd> key or by clicking, all the `key*` events will be enabled.

Comment: thanks..i forgot the concept of tab index..o have done the same thing in nitibkabra.com/table

Comment: The best suggestion is this. What kind of scrolling issues? Is it the same URL?

Comment: @NitinKabra **This webpage is not available**. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31325/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-nitin-kabra)

Comment: its nitinkabra.com/table ..sorry for the typo

Comment: This works after adding tabindex=0 and you control the navigation as you want. IE & FF both.

Comment: It took me significantly longer to find this then one would expect. I knew it HAD to have something to do with focus/blur or the lack there of, but adding tabindex never crossed my mind. Has there been any other improvements over the spec instead of having to do this to capture key events?

Comment: OMG, this really worked. My table wouldn't get focus for the keydown event and this little hack caused it to WORK!!

Comment: Maybe interesting: If the table should be focussable but not reachable via sequential keyboard navigation, you could use tabindex="-1" instead! (See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I created an input element and made it to disappear from screen with css like

```
<input type="text" id="tableEventShifter" style="position:absolute;z-index: -10;">
```

And add click event to table and at it's handler, trigger focus event to input element as

```
$("#myTable").on("click",function(e){
  $("#tableEventShifter").focus();
});
```

Finally, bind event handler on input element

```
$("#tableEventShifter").on("keydown", function(e) {
    var keyCode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    alert(keyCode);
});
```

Comment: that's pretty clever